# Using HammerJS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

Below I grab the container and on swipe left and right I trigger a click which is another function to do some fancy animation jazz.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
var hammertime = new Hammer(element);
hammertime.on('swiperight', function(ev) {
  $('.btn-left').trigger('click');
});
hammertime.on('swipeleft', function(ev) {
  $('.btn-right').trigger('click');
});
```

I keep getting this error about my `Hammerjs` library i've included (http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js) `Uncaught TypeError: a.addEventListener is not a function`.

I did some research and found another stackoverflow question that says I can't pass jQuery through `Hammerjs` thus I should use jQuery Hammer. I took a look at the repo and it's not been updated in nearly two years.

Do I need to use the jQuery Hammer (https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js) extension, or can I pass through jQuery without needing it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `new Hammer()` is expecting a single element, and `getElementsByClassName` is returning a `NodeList`.

If you change it to

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(element[0])
```

that should work as expected, since you'll be passing the first element that matches `.container`. If you want to bind it to all elements that have the `.container` class, you'll need to loop through them on your own. I rarely use jQuery for anything, so I usually include this little helper function for looping through NodeLists

```
function doToAll(elems, fn){
  var len = elems.length
  while(--len > -1){
    fn(elems[len])
  }
}
```

In this case, you'd use it like this:

```
doToAll(document.getElementsByClassName('container'), function(element){
  var hammertime = new Hammer(element)
  //add in the rest of your functionality
})
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you only ever expect a single `.container`, you could grab it with `document.querySelector('.container')`.